# Image source URI requiring authorization

Tags: c#, wpf

On my WPF `Window` I have an `Image` whose `UriSource` is set to the URL of some image on the internet.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="http://tinyurl.com/anmucph" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Everything works properly when I use a publicly accessible image on the internet: the WPF framework does the necessary HTTP GET request and displays the image.

What I want to do is use a `UriSource` that is a URL that requires the HTTP GET request to come with an Authorization header. (I have the required Authorization header string that I want to use.)

How do I use a `UriSource` that requires authorization?  Is there something built into WPF?  Or does this require a custom solution?  If so, how can I hook into the WPF framework to provide custom logic for performing the HTTP GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done with the tools built into WPF.

An alternative would be to create a lightweight and local HTTP proxy that has a single

- `GET http://localhost:####/proxy?uri={uri}&authorization={authorization}`

operation (where port #### is behind firewall) that in turn makes a

- `GET {uri}`

request with the supplied authorization header value.

You could then set `UriSource` to `http://localhost:####/proxy?uri=X&authorization=Y` where `X` is the URI-encoded URI of the secured resource you want to show and `Y` is the URI-encoded authorization header to send with the `GET` request.

Answer (score 3):

i know this is an old thread but i wanted to follow up with the solution i found.

.net has a cool feature to let you override it's core with your own methods on a system or application level.  this can be done for the WebRequest.Create method

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc0fhzk5.aspx

this post is a full example including IWebRequestCreate so you don't get stuck in recursion.

[Add header to all* HTTP requests on a machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217595/add-header-to-all-http-requests-on-a-machine)

after all this, everything in your application scope will be forced to use your create method.

NOTE: before adding your auth header, make sure you are on the right domain so you don't give out your auth to other places :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the username and password for the resource? You can specify the domain name like this if it's just standard HTTP auth:

```
http://username:password@tinyurl.com/anmucph
```

Comment: If I do this from a browser - I tried Chrome and Firefox - it will add on the appropriate "Basic Base64({username}:{password})" Authorization header.  But this doesn't seem to work in WPF.

Comment: This is [not supported in IE](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) and hence WPF won't work either!